# Winforms - Placing database operations above the form

Tags: labels

Good day everyone! I would like to confirm on something that relates to database operation.

Based on my research, we can use link labels as buttons and place real buttons when the function is more important than the other, until recently, someone said that buttons above the form (including link labels) would not be a very good idea. For him, it would break the standard of Windows Forms.

With my observations, if link labels were not a good idea to place above the rest of the form,  the UI of Windows 7's Explorer window would not also be a very good idea?

I was planning of placing database operations such as Add Record, Delete Record, Update Record, etc on a panel using link labels with it.

Comment: It's quite unclear what it is you're referring to here, and what your actual question is. Do you have a screenshot you can refer to so we're clear what you're referring to when you talk about the link label buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question. Are you asking if the below is ok?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fepd9a.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Generally speaking, such actions should be placed below the form. Also, I would strongly recomend against using links here instead of buttons. Links are more commonly used for navigation, or non-state changing actions (as always there are exceptions). Buttons would be a better fit here. If you're concerned about button priority, consider using contrasted colors and alignment to differentiate them.

Comment: When I converted my character-based UI app to a GUI, I kept my actions on top, and in the same order, because they were on top in the original app, but I took advantage of color-coded buttons.

Comment: @Kroehre: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. Thank you sir! :)